# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, foreach

It often happens to me to handle data that can be either an array or a null variable and to feed some `foreach` with these data.

```
$values = get_values();

foreach ($values as $value){
  ...
}
```

When you feed a foreach with data that are not an array, you get a warning:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [...]

Assuming it's not possible to refactor the `get_values()` function to always return an array (backward compatibility, not available source code, whatever other reason), I'm wondering which is the cleanest and most efficient way to avoid these warnings:

- Casting `$values` to array
- Initializing `$values` to array
- Wrapping the `foreach` with an `if`
- Other (please suggest)

Comment: It's highly possible the `$values` is not an array.

Answer (score 634, accepted):

There are three reasons that may cause this error:

1. A bug in the program. For example, get_values() is expected to return an array, but it returns something else. In this case you must start debugging the code, find the reason why get_values() doesn't return an array, and fix it.
2. get_values() may return an array or indicate that there is no data at all, by returning null (or false). In this case, you must add a condition which explicitly checks for this value, i.e.

   ```
    if ($values !== null)
    {
        foreach ($values as $value)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
   ```

   Here, PHP will be able to help you, by raising an alarm, when unexpected data type (i.e. neither null or array) would be provided (which means the bug in the code and you have to debug it again).
3. The code is just carelessly written and may return anything, so all you want is to get rid of this warning. But the most important part about warnings is that a programmer should never "avoid" (in the meaning or "silence") them.
   Warnings are programmer's friends, so don't waste their power. Properly organize your code the way it would only return expected data types. This way you will never get false alarms that have to be silenced. And at the same time PHP will be able to help you when unexpected data type would be provided (meaning that some code or input is not okay).
   When you have no control on the input data it would be a good idea to *validate* it before processing. In case an array is obligatory, then return an error and stop processing. In case an array is optional, initialize it as empty array. And so you won't see this error again.
   Only if don't care whether your input is boolean, or string or actually iterable you may use the approach below, which purpose is just to sweep the dirt under the rug:

   ```
    if (is_array($values) || is_object($values))
    {
        foreach ($values as $value)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Or use count() to figure out if array isn't empty

Comment: @Kemo: `count()` is not reliable.  If you pass `count()` null, it returns 0.  If you pass it a non-null, non-array argument, it returns 1.  Therefore it's impossible to use `count()` to determine if the variable is an array when the variable could be an empty array, or an array containing 1 item.

Comment: Note that some objects are iterable, and this answer doesn't account for those.

Comment: Should be `if (is_array($values) || $values instanceof Traversable)`.

Comment: It's a shame he didn't go on to say it wasn't for sure the most efficientest, though :D

Comment: [iterable objects and array type hinting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584700/iterable-objects-and-array-type-hinting)

Comment: Or...  you can cast to array inside foreach()

Comment: Remember if you checking for an invalid $value for foreach: `if (!is_array($values) && !is_object($values))`

Comment: Nowadays, `is_iterable()` is where it's at

Comment: @TheOnin is right... updated answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70870816

Answer (score 173):

How about this one? It's a lot cleaner and all in single line.

```
foreach ((array) $items as $item) {
 // ...
 }
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. For some reason, PHP didn't believe that the multidimensional array I built was actually an array of arrays.

Comment: Same here, this is a very nice fix for an array containing either arrays or null values. Simply add a test in the foreach loop to continue if the data is null.

Comment: Brilliant code, skipped the if, else for array and none-array value using $_POST with checkbox !

Comment: NOTE: While beautiful looking and resolves the invalid foreach warning, this method will return an undefined variable warning if the variable is not set in any way. Use `isset()` or `is_array()` or both, entirely depending on your scenario etc.

Comment: I had exactly the same situation Justin had with multi-dimensional arrays, and was surprised PHP errored on this.  I am coming from other languages usually, so this answer was perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pysis you guys are telling tales. PHP will **always** iterate a multidimensional array. You surely won't be able to prove your words with a code example. While a much more plausible explanation is just **you** wrote some bad code, but blamed foreach for it.

Comment: Very cool, i nearly forgot about PHP has this...

Answer (score 50):

I usually use a construct similar to this:

```
/**
 * Determine if a variable is iterable. i.e. can be used to loop over.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_iterable($var)
{
    return $var !== null 
        && (is_array($var) 
            || $var instanceof Traversable 
            || $var instanceof Iterator 
            || $var instanceof IteratorAggregate
            );
}

$values = get_values();

if (is_iterable($values))
{
    foreach ($values as $value)
    {
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Note that this particular version is not tested, its typed directly into SO from memory.

**Edit:** added [Traversable](http://php.net/Traversable) check

Comment: You may be able to remove the other two classes, @Kris.  They both extend **[Traversable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php)** now and seem to have been born that way in 5.0.0.  Though I'm feeling a tiny doubt as to whether instanceof always applied to extends.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone: yes (except they are interfaces, not classes) However; I put Traversable in before those, neither Iterator nor IteratorAggregate would ever need verifying (this way they won't slow down execution). I left them in to keep the answer as close as possible to the original answer I gave and to keep it obvious/readable.

Comment: I think it'd be fair to add `is_object($var)` re. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: @MarkFox: Feel free, however I intentionally left it out; I've never seen a use for it that wasn't better served by implementing `Iterator` or `IteratorAggregate`, but that's of course just my opinion and therefor subjective (I never use public fields).

Comment: @kris `stdClass` doesn't implement these interfaces, therefore I would be in favour for `is_object` as well. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61312

Comment: @WilliamGeorge, You could if you wanted to traverse public fields but I actively choose not to view a single objects' properties as a list or collection. there is no guarantee that all properties are homogenous. in other words, I consider traversing an objects properties to be either a very bad idea or too specialized a case. (would prefer using reflection in either case)

Comment: @hakre: your edit completely changes the behaviour and meaning of my answer and negates its entire purpose. Your "edit" is better suited to be an answer on its own.

Comment: I'd replace the $var !== null by !empty($var), just one reason: the empty string "" counts as traversable but will raise the Invalid argument exception.

Answer (score 20):

**Please do not depend on casting as a solution**,
even though others are suggesting this as a valid option to prevent an error, it might cause another one.

**Be aware:** If you expect a specific form of array to be returned, this might fail you. More checks are required for that.

> E.g. casting a boolean to an array `(array)bool`, will **NOT** result in an empty array, but an array with one element containing the boolean value as an int: `[0=>0]` or `[0=>1]`.

[I wrote a quick test to present this problem](https://3v4l.org/aO76k).
(Here is a [backup Test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9384a9343369c4d5f5fb1448ab83984a04d2faf1) in case the first test url fails.)

Included are tests for: `null`, `false`, `true`, a `class`, an `array` and `undefined`.

---

**Always test your input before using it in foreach. Suggestions:**

1. [Quick type checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach/2630032#2630032): `$array = is_array($var) or is_object($var) ? $var : [] ;`
2. [Type hinting arrays](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.typehinting.php) in methods before using a foreach and [specifying return types](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types)
3. Wrapping foreach within if
4. Using `try{}catch(){}` blocks
5. Designing proper code / testing before production releases
6. To test an array against proper form you could use `array_key_exists` on a specific key, [or test the depth of an array (when it is one !)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263621/1408287).
7. Always extract your helper methods into the global namespace in a way to reduce duplicate code

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
//Force array
$dataArr = is_array($dataArr) ? $dataArr : array($dataArr);
foreach ($dataArr as $val) {
  echo $val;
}
```

;)

Comment: This won't work well with associative arrays.. The is_array method is overall better... and easier...

Answer (score 8):

All answers provided above are essentially just error suppression.

Your PHP is telling you that you are trying to use a variable of incorrect type, and there is possibly an error. but all answers provided are just brushing this message off.

Your best bet is to initialize every variable before use. And to make return types strict and explicit. You must ask yourself, WHY `get_values()` is returning anything than array? Why it cannot be made to return just an empty array, if no data found? Surely it can be.

Comment: Casting is an option - if you initialise an array using `$array = (array)null;` you get an empty array.  Of course it's a waste of memory allocation ;-)

Comment: +1: read from a sentimental point of view, I don't care if the language can do without, variables _MUST_ be declared and unreliable results _MUST_ be checked. It's required to keep the developer(s) sane and the error logs short.

Comment: This is *far and away* the best answer to this question. If you're trying to iterate something then you clearly expect it to be iterable. Casting it or checking if it is iterable is a waste of time as all it does is mask the fact that the variable doesn't contain what you think it does, which means the *actual* problem is somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach ($arr ?: [] as $elem) {
    // Do something
}
```

This doesen't check if it is an array, but skips the loop if the variable is null or an empty array.

Update from PHP 7.0 you should use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
foreach ($arr ?? [] as $elem) {
    // Do something
}
```

This would solve the warning mentioned in the comment ([here](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/whats-the-difference-between-null-coalescing-operator-and-ternary-operator-in-php#vs) a handy table that compares `?:` and `??` outputs).

Comment: This produces a PHP warning "Cannot use a scalar value as an array" when $arr is invalid. You can create an empty array beforehand and then refer to that instead of []. But that can sometimes produce a separate problem when using $elem as a reference like "&$elem" so I wouldn't recommend either method now.

Answer (score 6):

```
$values = get_values();

foreach ((array) $values as $value){
  ...
}
```

Problem is always null and Casting is in fact the cleaning solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using php7 and you want to handle only undefined errors this is the cleanest IMHO

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
foreach ( $array ?? [] as $item ) {
  echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**As of PHP >= 7.1.0 use `is_iterable`**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php

```
if (is_iterable($value)) {
    foreach ($value as $v) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Warning invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` display tweets.
go to `/wp-content/plugins/display-tweets-php`.
Then insert this code on line number 591, It will run perfectly.

```
if (is_array($tweets)) {
    foreach ($tweets as $tweet) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

More concise extension of [@Kris's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15655476/2936460)

```
function secure_iterable($var)
{
    return is_iterable($var) ? $var : array();
}

foreach (secure_iterable($values) as $value)
{
     //do stuff...
}
```

especially for using inside template code

```
<?php foreach (secure_iterable($values) as $value): ?>
    ...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `return is_iterable($var) ? $var : array($var);`?

Answer (score 2):

There seems also to be a relation to the environment:

I had that "invalid argument supplied foreach()" error only in the dev environment, but not in prod (I am working on the server, not localhost).

Despite the error a var_dump indicated that the array was well there (in both cases app and dev).

The `if (is_array($array))` around the `foreach ($array as $subarray)` solved the problem.

Sorry, that I cannot explain the cause, but as it took me a while to figure a solution I thought of better sharing this as an observation.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptional case for this notice occurs if you set array to null inside foreach loop

```
if (is_array($values))
{
    foreach ($values as $value)
    {
        $values = null;//WARNING!!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This warning is happening because the array that you want use is empty, you can use of below condition:

```
if ($your_array != false){
   foreach ($your_array as $value){
         echo $value['your_value_name'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a combination of `empty`, `isset` and `is_array` as

```
$array = ['dog', 'cat', 'lion'];

if (!empty($array) && isset($array) && is_array($array) {
    //loop
    foreach ($array as $values) {
        echo $values; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use is_array function, when you will pass array to foreach loop.**

```
if (is_array($your_variable)) {
  foreach ($your_variable as $item) {
   //your code
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution:

```
$type = gettype($your_iteratable);
$types = array(
    'array',
    'object'
);

if (in_array($type, $types)) {
    // foreach code comes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about defining an empty array as fallback if `get_value()` is empty?
I can't think of a shortest way.

```
$values = get_values() ?: [];

foreach ($values as $value){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    foreach ($checkbox as $key) {
       echo $key . '<br>';
    }
}

?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="red">red <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="green">green <br>
```

Comment: -1, If `$yourArray = 1;` it will try to iterate, and you will get the error.  `empty()` is not a suitable test.

Comment: @BradKoch is absolutely right. is_array() is the only reliable way of testing whether $yourArray is an array. See other answers for details on why is_array() is not sufficient--foreach can handle iterators as well.