# Invalid argument supplied for foreach!

Tags: foreach, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

I have the following code:

```
<?
foreach($format as $form)
{
    echo $form;
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?
        $s = $database->onlineFormatUsers($form);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($s))
        {
            $username=$row['username'];
            $id=$row['id'];?>
            <li><a href="../userprofile.php?id=<?echo $id?>"><?echo "$username";?></a></li>
        <?
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?
}
?>

<? 
//the active formats
$f = $database->activeFormats();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($f))
{
    $format=$row['name'];
}
?>
```

It is saying its an invalid argument?
Any reason why?
Thanks

Comment: Please show where `$format` comes from.

Comment: Can you give us a `print_r` or `var_dump` of `$format`, prior to the foreach loop?

Comment: $format seems to be populated after the foreach rather than before. Move the processing of the DB output to before the foreach. You should still use a check for array just in case nothing is returned from the database.

Comment: Yeah it was before, i just added it for you to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$format` is probably not an array.

Wrap the `foreach` block in an `if(is_array($format)) { }` block or cast it to an array by doing `$format = (array)$format`.

Comment: Oh does format need to be a array?
I will edit to show where $format comes from.

Comment: Yes, `foreach` only works on arrays.

Comment: instead of doing $format = (array)$format; you can just instantly do foreach((array)$format as $form)

Comment: @xeross Yeah, you can. I prefer to cast it separately for readability - it's easy to pass right over the casting if it's within the foreach call - but that's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure $format is an array ? put an

```
<?php echo gettype($format); ?>
```

before the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

$format is not array or not exists!
Before foreach

```
if(is_array($format)){  
   foreach($format ...
}
```