# Is there a way to test a variable for "isForEachable"

Tags: php, iterator, foreach

Using PHP, is there a function/method/way to check if a variable contains something that would be safe to put into a foreach construct?  Something like

```
//the simple case, would probably never use it this bluntly
function foo($things)
{
    if(isForEachable($things))
    {
        foreach($things as $thing)
        {
            $thing->doSomething();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Can't foreach over variable");
    }
}
```

If your answer is "setup a handler to catch the PHP error", your efforts are appreciated, but I'm looking for something else.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584700/iterable-objects-and-array-type-hinting/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, sort of. You can do:

```
if (is_array($var) || ($var instanceof Traversable)) {
    //...
}
```

However, this doesn't guarantee the `foreach` loop will be successful. It may throw an exception or fail silently. The reason is that some iterable objects, at some point, may not have any information to yield (for instance, they were already iterated and it only makes sense to iterate them once).

See [`Traversable`](http://php.net/Traversable). Arrays are not objects and hence cannot implement such interface (they predate it), but they can be traversed in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: e.g. DOMNodeList is also a object with its own method but strangely its foreach compatible and its !is_array(...).

Comment: note that objects are foreachable as well, so you may wish to add `|| is_object($var)` to the conditional.

Answer (score 6):

### PHP 7

Recent versions of PHP have [`is_iterable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php) and the [`iterable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) pseudo-type.

---

### PHP 5

Since all objects and arrays are "[foreachable](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)" in PHP 5+...

```
function is_foreachable($var) {
  return is_array($var) || is_object($var);
}
```

Comment: Is_iterable is still not useful tho. It will return false on object that are foreachable.

Answer (score -2):

Check using [`is_array`](http://php.net/is_array)

```
if( is_array($things) )
      echo "it is foreachable";
else
      echo "Not it's not foreachable.";
```

Comment: The `foreach` loop supports much more than arrays.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Apologies, my bad. I don't use PHP OOP much.