# Is there an is_iterable or similar function for PHP?

Tags: php, iterator, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterable objects and array type hinting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584700/iterable-objects-and-array-type-hinting)

I am passing a JSON'd feed from Twitter into my application, and sometimes Twitters API returns empty or incomplete feeds. This is causing a problem when I try to iterate the feeds using `foreach` - does anyone know of a suitable test to find out if an object or array is iterable?

Could this be done with `isarray($obj) || $obj instanceof Iterator` or are there any other cases I should look out for?

Comment: See NullUserException's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584700/iterable-objects-and-array-type-hinting)

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584700/iterable-objects-and-array-type-hinting/3584781#3584781 Credit to boltclock