# how can i stop' Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 'from being reported on website front end

Tags: php, sql

`PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/synergie/public_html/ss/libraries/joomla/database/database/mysql.php on line 377`

It comes up intermittently but often in both front and back of my joomla website. I am not expert in this area but it appears to be out of scope for everyone I ask for help. Since I cannot stop the error from occurring I was hoping you could help me to disable or block  it from reporting.

this is the code I am dealing with:

```
  // If we want the whole field data object add that to the list.
            //else
            {
                foreach ($fields as $field)
                {
                    $result[$field->Field] = $field;
                }
            }

            return $result;
```

Comment: Stop supplying invalid arguments.

Comment: thankyou that is wonderful advice.

Comment: @titus1972 It actually is wonderful advice. In designing PHP you should fix errors, not hide them.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder That's what I said thanks for the wonderful advice the disabling the error thing, that is simply a temporary measure until I can actually address the root cause itself. But Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @titus1972 My apologizes. I thought I detected a hint of sarcasm in your comment. I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you're looping through an array and not an object? Just to be sure, consider changing to:

```
foreach((array)$fields as $field)
{
    $result[$field->Field] = $field;
}
```

Comment: I had no idea typecasting would work, brilliant way to keep it on one line!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a try catch block?

```
try {
    foreach( $array as $v ) {
        // do dtuff
    }
} catch( Exception $e ) {
    echo 'Caught exception';
}
```

Comment: try / catch does not work for those kind of warnings unless you convert them into exceptions which is easily possible with [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/ErrorException).

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off error reporting with this function:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is a production environment and you simply want to disable warning messages like this (I'm assuming that this is code that you didn't write since you mention Joomla), try disabling error reporting in your php.ini file.

Change:

```
display_errors On
```

to

```
display_errors Off
```

Note that if this is a development environment you should probably leave error reporting on and fix any warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hiding the error, you should be checking that you are passing something [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) to [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). You can do that with [@NullUserException's `is_iterable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3584781/568785):

```
function is_iterable($var) {
    return (is_array($var) || $var instanceof Traversable);
}

if(is_iterable($fields)) {
     foreach($fields as $field) {
         // Processing $field here
     }
} else {
    echo "Fields is not iterable";
}
```

Comment: is_array() is probably the most simple way to check, but this is certainly more exhaustive

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely choose the syntax:

```
if(is_array($fields)){
    foreach($fields as $field){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Be careful by using the nice and attractive short form :

```
foreach((array)$fields as $field)
```

if $fields contains complex data structure (not a simple array) the casting may compromise your content.