# invalid argument and illegal offset

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have a page in my web application, where I type some text inside an `<input type="search"` and I choose from a drop list, a type to complete my search action, then when I click on search submit button, the web app go to MySQL and search for rows then show them to me in HTML table.

I have this SQL code that it is placed on top of my HTML page:

```
<?php
require_once('../include/global.php');
$result6 = 0;
$message = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit_search']))
{
    $selected = $_POST['select_search_type'];
    $search = $_POST['search_item'];
    try
    {
        if($selected=="item_name")
        {
            $query = ("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE item_name= :search");
            $stmt6 = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt6->bindParam(":search", $search);
            $count6 = $stmt6->execute();
            $result6 = $stmt6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        
        if($selected=="item_cat")
        {
            $query = ("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE item_cat= :search");
            $stmt6 = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt6->bindParam(":search", $search);
            $count6 = $stmt6->execute();
            $result6 = $stmt6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        if($selected=="item_code")
        {
            $query = ("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE item_code= :search");
            $stmt6 = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt6->bindParam(":search", $search);
            $count6 = $stmt6->execute();
            $result6 = $stmt6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

And in the webpage HTML form I have this code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="search" name="search_item"/>
<select id="selectW" name="select_search_type">
<option value="select_search">select</option>
<option value="item_name">product</option>
<option value="item_cat">category</option>
<option value="item_code">code</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit_search" value="search"/>
</form>
</div>
<div id="section2">
<form action="" method="post">
<table class="imagetable" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th align="center">product</th>
<th align="center">code</th>
<th align="center">price</th>
<th align="center">number</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($result6 as $show_search) { //var_dump($show_search);?>
<tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo $show_search['item_name'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $show_search['item_code'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $show_search['buy_price'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $show_search['item_sold'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table> 
</form>
```

Now, when I run and test my page, the first error was:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

So I changed `result6 = 0;` into `result6 = array();`. but I got the same warning.

Then after that, when I type a name in search text box, I got this error when submitting my search:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'item_code'
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'item_name'
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'buy_price'
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'item_sold'

I tried this code [in this link but still the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572061/php-warning-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Then I saw [this link here for the illegal offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php) but it is not relevant with my code (Don't worth to test, different code).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: before a foreach you'd better to test the existance of your variable with a if isset($myvariable)

Comment: nope, still the same

Comment: have you tried to debug with a echo "<pre>";var_dump($_POST);echo "</pre>"; to show the value of your post data ?

Comment: still the same error, even var_dump($show_result) is not showing

Comment: What does it look like if you do a `var_dump($result6)` ? It might be possible that your PHP search script is not running properly or returning the result you believe it is. Also, I would absolutely recommend that you use a conditional to display your results as @SylvainMARTIN suggested. However, as you are defining the variable globally in your PHP, i would use `if( ! is_empty($result6) ) { run your foreach(); }` to only run that if the array has data inside of it.

Comment: From the troubleshooting you've done, it seems pretty clear that your `$result6` variable is empty and not set. So either your queries aren't running or aren't returning any data. Remember, the way you have them written, they will only return EXACT matches.

Comment: I did use your conditions, but still getting the same result, I hope to get more help

Answer (score 0):

Please be adviced, you are iterating over the result of [http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php] fetch, and no on the entire resultset, that is why you get 'illegal string offset'

Remove '$result6 = $stmt6...' and then please iterate over the statement...

```
<?php foreach ($stmt6 as $show_search) { //var_dump($show_search);?>
<tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo $show_search['item_name'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $show_search['item_code'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $show_search['buy_price'] ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $show_search['item_sold'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: nope, still getting an invalid argument for foreach

Comment: Can you provide the entire page source? in which order are you trying to do that?