# PHP parse array posted from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

**I have this jQuery code that adds to an array inside an $each loop:**

```
new_edit = {};
new_edit['file_id'] = $file_id;
new_edit['file_realname'] = $new_file_realname;
new_edit['file_folder'] = $new_file_folder;
new_file_edits.push(JSON.stringify(new_edit));
```

**jQuery new_file_edits array output**

```
{"file_id":"1857","file_realname":"dddd[1].mp4","file_folder":"/"}, 
{"file_id":"1856","file_realname":"aaaa[1].jpg","file_folder":"/"},
{"file_id":"1855","file_realname":"ssss[1].jpg","file_folder":"/"}
```

**and im trying to post it to call.php like this:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/call.php",
    data: "edit_files="+ arrayVarHere,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(msg){
            alert(+msg);
        }
    });
```

**In the PHP file call.php i have this code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_files'])){
    $edit_array = $_POST['edit_files'];
    $file_array = array();
    foreach($edit_array as $key => $value){
        $file_array[$key] = $value;
    }
print_r($file_array);
    die();
}
```

but i get this error and i cant figure out how to fix it, been googling it for a while now...

error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home2/dddd/public_html/call.php on line 237

Line 237: `foreach($edit_array as $key => $value){`

Any help is much appreciated!

-Morten

**EDIT 1:**
I changed `$edit_array = $_POST['edit_files'];` to `$edit_array = array($_POST['edit_files']);`

And now it outputs:

```
{"file_id":"1857","file_realname":"dddd[1].mp4","file_folder":"/"}, 
{"file_id":"1856","file_realname":"aaaa[1].jpg","file_folder":"/"},
{"file_id":"1855","file_realname":"ssss[1].jpg","file_folder":"/"}
```

How do i go from here with the `foreach($edit_array as $key => $value){` part?

**Edit 2:**
**i build my arrayVarHere like this:**

```
$.each( $selected_files_array, function( index, value ){
//i get $file_id, $new_file_realname and $new_file_folder with some code here
        new_edit = {};
        new_edit['file_id'] = $file_id;
        new_edit['file_realname'] = $new_file_realname;
        new_edit['file_folder'] = $new_file_folder;
        arrayVarHere.push(JSON.stringify(new_edit));
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572061/php-warning-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Comment: Is $edit_array an array?

Comment: Check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2630013/5447994

Comment: data: {edit_files : arrayVarHere},

Comment: I updated the post with an edit, any ideas?

Comment: How can i output file_realname for each file_id in the array?

Comment: can you show how you're building `arrayVarHere` ?   something like `arrayVarHere = JSON.stringify(new_edit)`  ??

Comment: ok updated the post with Edit 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955017/sending-json-to-php-using-ajax

Comment: You're not sending JSON to the server, you're sending a normal POST query (that happens to contain a JSON string).

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this:

data: "edit_files="+ arrayVarHere,

Answer (score 0):

call json data by `json_decode` in call.php

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_files'])){
$edit_array = json_decode($_POST['edit_files'],true); //return array 
$file_array = array();
foreach($edit_array as $key => $value){
    $file_array[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($file_array);
die();
}
```

in your ajax alert should be

```
 success: function(msg){
            alert(msg); //remove plus sign ,this can output `NaN`
        }
```

Comment: How can i output file_realname for each file_id in the array?

Comment: what will output `$key` and `$value` in foreach

Answer (score 0):

check **edit_array** is array print_r($edit_array);

check **contentType** is used form data then correct otherwise used json type

if form data then check **data: edit_files[]: arrayVarHere**,

Answer (score 0):

It returns this array

```
Array ( [0] => [{"file_id":"1857","file_realname":"aq53pop_460sv[1].mp4","file_folder":"/"},{"file_id":"1859","file_realname":"aKqbD8Q_460sv[1].mp4","file_folder":"/"},{"file_id":"1856","file_realname":"aDopymK_700b[1].jpg","file_folder":"/"}] )
```

how can i loop the array and access file_id value etc?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing Data to PHP may not be that ideal. Here is what might get you started:

**PHP: call.php**

```
    <?php

        $data0      = isset($_POST['data_0']) ? json_decode($_POST['data_0'], true) : null;
        $data1      = isset($_POST['data_1']) ? json_decode($_POST['data_1'], true) : null;
        $data2      = isset($_POST['data_2']) ? json_decode($_POST['data_2'], true) : null;

        $arrData    = array(
            'data0' => $data0,
            'data1' => $data1,
            'data2' => $data2,
        );

        foreach($arrData as $dataKey=>$dataObject){
            $tempFileID     = $dataObject->file_id;
            $tempFileName   = $dataObject->file_realname;
            $tempFileFolder = $dataObject->file_folder;

            // DO SOMETHING WITH THESE DATA AND THEN BUILD UP A RESPONSE FOR AJAX + SEND IT...

            // UNCOMMENT TO SEE THE DATA IN YOUR NETWORKS CONSOLE BUT 
            // IF YOU DO THIS (SINCE YOU EXPECT JSON RESPONSE) YOUR AJAX WILL RESPOND WITH AN ERROR...
            // var_dump($dataObject);
        }

        // RESPOND WITH THE SAME DATA YOU RECEIVED FROM AJAX: JUST FOR TESTING PURPOSES... 
        die( json_encode($arrData));

    ?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT: BUILDING THE DATA FOR PHP**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataForPHP              = {};
        var iCount                  = 0;

        $.each( $selected_files_array, function( index, value ){
            var keyName                 = "data_" + iCount;
            new_edit                    = {};
            new_edit['file_id']         = $file_id;
            new_edit['file_realname']   = $new_file_realname;
            new_edit['file_folder']     = $new_file_folder;
            dataForPHP[keyName]         = new_edit;
            iCount++;
        });
    </script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT: AJAX REQUEST**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type        : "POST",
            url         : "/call.php",
            datatype    : "JSON",
            data        : dataForPHP,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",

            success: function(msg){
                if(msg){
                    alert("Ajax Succeeded");
                    console.log(msg);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```