# validate form in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate a form of a test.  I get an error in answer.php  Basically I want to validate that each question has been answered.

**The form:**

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '$tid' ORDER BY q_nr";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
echo "<form method='post' name='form1' action='answer.php'>";
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $q_nr=$row1['q_nr'];
    $q_type=$row1['q_type'];
    $question=$row1['question'];
    $option1=$row1['option1'];
    $option2=$row1['option2'];
    $option3=$row1['option3'];
echo "<P><strong>$q_nr $question</strong><BR>";
echo "<BR>";
echo "</p>";
if ($q_type != 'mr') {
if($option1!="") {
echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='A'>$option1<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; }
if($option2!="") {
echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='B'>$option2<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; }
if($option3!="") {
echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='C'>$option3<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; }
} else { // else if not <> mr
if($option1!="") {
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='question[$q_nr][]' value='A'>$option1<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; } 
if($option2!="") {
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='question[$q_nr][]' value='B'>$option2<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; } 
if($option3!="") {
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='question[$q_nr][]' value='C'>$option3<BR>";
} else {
echo ''; } 
} //end else if q_type <> mr
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "</p>";
} //end while row1
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='Submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

**answer.php**

```
foreach($_POST['question'] as $key => $ans) {
if ($ans[] = '') {
echo "answer is empty";
}
}
```

**I get the error:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ......**

Comment: What do you get if you enter print_r($_POST) in answer.php?

Comment: Please check my edit in the answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your `$_POST['question']` is empty. This is what happens when you try to do this with an empty array.

Whereas your HTML says: `name='question[$q_nr]'`.

Print the values in the array to see what it contains, use `print_r`.

Edit: `$_POST['question']` IS NOT an array! While `$_POST` IS an array...

Maybe you should try to do something like this: 
`foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)`

Or do it however you want the result to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you, I used print_r($_POST); and get the output:  Array ( [question_1] => A ) 
 and then underneath it:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: try `if( is_array( $_POST['question'] ) ) {
    foreach ( $_POST['question'] as $key=>$value ) { ...
} else {
    echo "$_POST['question'] isn't an array";
}` and think of variable variables

Comment: wait a minute... How come $_POST['question'] is an array in your case? in your case $_POST IS an array, but not $_POST['question']

Comment: OK you have put me in the right direction here.  If I only use $_POST in my foreach I don't get the error any more, but my if statement still gives no output to validate the form.  Sigh.

Comment: Still wanted to add:

`foreach($_POST as $key => $ans) {
echo $key;
echo $ans;
if (empty($_POST)) {
echo "empty";
} else {
echo "not empty";
}
}`

Comment: That's because $ans in this case is not an array. Try `$ans` instead of `$ans[]` out and tell me what you got :)

Comment: what I've managed to do now is actually get a results.  I think what is happening it is not doing the foreach because no answers was selected in the test.  If I move the 'if(empt($_POST)) to in front of the foreach, I get a result.  How am I going to check if each question was answered if it is not doing the foreach?

Answer (score 2):

One thing is that you are assigning the answer rather than checking it, use `==`

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $ans) {
  if ($ans == '') {
    echo "answer is empty";
  }
}
```

and instead of using

```
name='question[$q_nr]'
```

I would use for the radio fields

```
name='question_{$q_nr}'
```

and for the checkboxes

```
name='question_{$q_nr}[]'
```

On answer.php you should be able to do a print_r($_POST) to check what you are getting.

Comment: I've done what you suggested:  1. Changed to echo "<input type='radio' name='question_$q_nr[]' value='A'>$option1<BR>"; but now I get an error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ...

Comment: Sorry meant to wrap in curly braces, have changed above.

Comment: The curly braces explicitly specify the end of the name of the variable.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I've changed the form, and also changed the action page to use == instead of = but it's still complaining, I'll keep on trying and report back.

Comment: You will also have to change the `foreach` statement as your post names are no longer the question array they are 'question_1','question_2'

Comment: sorry, I've changed my foreach to the following but I still get the same error.  Any ideas?  foreach($_POST['question_{$q_nr}[]'] as $key => $ans) {
if ($ans == '') {
    echo "answer is empty";
}
}