# Not to loop the key with empty value in a multidimensional array

Tags: oop, multidimensional-array, foreach, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

How can I not to loop the key with empty value in an array?

For instance, I want to skip `[submit] =>` or `[submit] => add` from being looped in `foreach`,

```
Array ( 
[cart] => Array ( [1386638969582999] => Array ( [quantity_stock] => 10 ) ) 
[submit] => 
)
```

the loop,

```
foreach ($_POST as $index => $array_items) 
{
    foreach($array_items as $id => $item)
    {
        $cart->add_item($id);
    }


}
```

I get this error,

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:... on line xx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `is_array()` to test if the key refers to an array:

```
foreach ($_POST as $index => $array_items) 
{
    // $_POST['submit'] won't be processed since it isn't an array
    if (is_array($array_items))
    {
      foreach($array_items as $id => $item)
      {
          $cart->add_item($id);
      }
    }
}
```