# unexpected warning in zend pagination

Tags: php, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

my controllar action is

```
public function indexAction(){
 Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('index.phtml');
  $params = array('host'        =>'localhost',
                  'username'    =>'root',
                        'password'  =>'',
                        'dbname'    =>'test'
                         );
   $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($params);
    $select = $db->select()->from('tableviewdemo');
    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($select);

    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page', 1));
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
    $this->view->paginator=$paginator;
}
```

and view file is

```
<?  echo "<table border=1>";
foreach ($this->paginator as $item) {
echo '<tr><td>' . $item['id'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $item['name'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $item['city'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $item['state'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $item['date'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $item['zip'] . '</td></tr>';}
echo "</table>";
echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator,'Sliding','/test/index.phtml'); ?>
```

it is showing error
table and pagelink as following
First | < Previous | Next > | Last

and warning 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\Administrator\hello\application\views\scripts\test\index.phtml
why this happening????

Comment: `var_dump($this->paginator)`, what is the result?

Comment: object(Zend_Paginator)[48]
  protected '_cacheEnabled' => boolean true
  protected '_adapter' =>

Answer (score 0):

You only pass any variable except arrays to foreach if it implements the interface iterators , I think Zend_Paginator doesn't implement it . and You are using paginator for listing it is totally unexeptable just try this

```
$this->view->records = $db->select()->from('tableviewdemo')->fetchAll()->toArray();
```

and iterate in your view file

```
foreach($this->records)
{
}
```

I have also doubt that your db query is working or not.

Comment: db query is working perfactly, i have already done your thing ...so how can i paginate my table...

Comment: you have already echo the paginator echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator,'Sliding','/test/index.phtml'); ?> go in test/index.phtml and see what is going on there remove foreach of paginator you have added

Comment: if i remove foreach then it's showing nothing but paginator link.....giving ...Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,

Comment: Zend_Paginator implements Countable and IteratorAggregate so foreach works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you set `index.phtml` as your default view partial, to misquote a quote ... *I don't think that method does what you think it does.*

At least in the beginning I suggest you specify everything. Specify the select(), specify the adapter, create a new paginator. Later you can take the short cuts.

```
public function indexAction(){
    $params = array('host'      =>'localhost',
                    'username'  =>'root',
                    'password'  =>'',
                    'dbname'    =>'test'
                    );
    $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($params);
    $select = $db->select()->from('tableviewdemo');
    //specify paginator adapter
    $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);
    //instantiate the paginator
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
    //if you really have to use the factory, don't forget the string for the adapter.
    //The paginator should work without the string, but may not work as expected.
    //$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($select, 'DbTableSelect');    
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page', 1));
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
    //assign paginator to the view
    $this->view->paginator=$paginator;
}
```

**A note on adapters.**

The biggest *apparent* difference between the adapters `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTable` and `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect` is that *DbTable* returns an aray will use the array notation `$item['name']` and *DbTableSelect* returns an object (rowset object) uses object notation `$item->name' so use the adapter appropriate to your needs.

To get back to my original point. The default view partial does not refer the page you want displayed. It refers to the view partial that contains the controls for your paginator. Zend does not have a default implementation of pagination controls just an [example](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html#zend.paginator.usage.rendering.example-controls).

Try this in your view.

```
<!-- assumes you using DbTableSelect paginator adapter -->
<!-- for DbSelect adapter just change to array notation: $item['id'] -->
<table border=1>
<?php foreach ($this->paginator as $item) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($item->id) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($item->name) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($item->city) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($item->state) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($item->date) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($item->zip) ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php endForeach ?>
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator,'Sliding','MyPaginatorControl.phtml'); ?>
```

The paginator I typically use is very similar to the example in the manual, I call it in my view script (the default location for all partial views is `views/scripts`) :

```
<?php
    echo $this->paginationControl(
        //remember the third parameter is the controls partial
        $this->paginator, 'Sliding', '_paginatorControl.phtml'
    )
 ?>
```

Just in case someone needs it here is my basic control partial:

```
//views/scripts/_paginatorControl.phtml. Yes. I just copy this file to where ever I need it.
<?php
if ($this->pageCount) :
    //you need to add each of the request parameters to url
    $params = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                    ->getRequest()->getParams();
    //remove the system parameters
    unset($params['module']);
    unset($params['controller']);
    unset($params['action']);
    ?>
    <div class="paginationControl">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!--First Page Link -->
                    <?php if (isset($this->first)): ?>
                        <a href="<?php
                echo $this->url(array_merge($params, array('page' => $this->first)))
                        ?>">
                            &lt; First</a>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <span class="disabled">&lt; First</span>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </td>
                <td class="space">|</td>
                <td>
                    <!--Previous Page Links-->
                    <?php if (isset($this->previous)) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php
                echo $this->url(array_merge($params, array('page' => $this->previous)))
                        ?>">
                            &lt; Prev</a>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <span class="disabled">&lt; Prev</span>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </td>
                <td>|
                    <!--Number page links-->
                    <?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
                        <?php if ($page != $this->current) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php
                echo $this->url(array_merge($params, array('page' => $page)))
                            ?>">
                                <?php echo $page ?></a> |
                        <?php else: ?>
                                <?php echo $page ?> |
                            <?php
                            endif;
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--Next page link-->
                    <?php if (isset($this->next)) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php
                echo $this->url(array_merge($params, array('page' => $this->next)))
                        ?>">
                            Next &gt;</a>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <span class="disabled">Next &gt;</span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="space">|</td>
                <td>
                    <!--Last page Link -->
                    <?php if (isset($this->last)): ?>
                        <a href="<?php
                echo $this->url(array_merge($params, array('page' => $this->last)))
                        ?>">
                            Last &gt;</a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <span class="disabled">last &gt;</span>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this helps.