# Something weird with API Instagram, "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php, api, foreach, instagram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

well, the code worked perfectly, until today I noticed this error "`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../www/wp-content/themes/.../functions.php on line 93`" and do not know what can be, I think Instagram has changed something in their API, or not.

I've tried changing access key but failed.

Follow the code

```
function get_instagram($user_id=-ID-,$count=15,$width=45,$height=45){

        $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/media/recent/?access_token=-ACCESS-TOKEN-&count='.$count;

        //salva em cache 1h
        $cache = 'temp/instagram.json';
        if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){

            $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
        } else {
            $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
            file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
        }


        $result = '<ul id="instagram-list">'.PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
            $result .= "\t".'<li><a href="'.$value->link.'" target="_blank" >
                              <img src="'.$value->images->low_resolution->url.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" />
                              </a> </li>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
        $result .= '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
        return $result;
    }
```

sorry my bad english

Comment: What does `file_get_contents($url);` return?  Its failing to decode json properly or the structure is slightly different.

Comment: Is $jsonData->data an array or an object?

Comment: It may be something like $jsonData->data[0]