# MagicSeaweed API JSON Array

Tags: php, json

The [MSW API](http://magicseaweed.com/developer/api) states:

> Our API follows RESTful convention. Querying for information for a location is as simple as calling: http://magicseaweed.com/api/YOURAPIKEY/forecast/?spot_id=10
>
> You’ll receive a JSON array consisting of a series of data representing the forecast for specific timeframes, looking like this:

```
[
{
    "timestamp": 1367366400,
    "localTimestamp": 1367366400,
    "issueTimestamp": 1367366400,
    "fadedRating": 0,
    "solidRating": 0,
    "swell": {
        "minBreakingHeight": 1,
        "absMinBreakingHeight": 0.504,
        "maxBreakingHeight": 1,
        "absMaxBreakingHeight": 0.784,
        "unit": "ft",
        "components": {
            "combined": {
                "height": 1.6,
                "period": 5,
                "direction": 252.47,
                "compassDirection": "ENE"
            },
            "primary": {
                "height": 0.5,
                "period": 7,
                "direction": 92.49,
                "compassDirection": "W"
            },
            "secondary": {
                "height": 0.2,
                "period": 9,
                "direction": 52.9,
                "compassDirection": "SW"
            },
            "tertiary": {
                "height": 1.5,
                "period": 5,
                "direction": 248.62,
                "compassDirection": "ENE"
            }
        }
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 6,
        "direction": 221,
        "compassDirection": "NE",
        "chill": 32,
        "gusts": 9,
        "unit": "mph"
    },
    "condition": {
        "pressure": 1026,
        "temperature": 39,
        "weather": "10",
        "unitPressure": "mb",
        "unit": "f"
    },
    "charts": {
        "swell": "htt://chart-1-us.msw.ms/wave/750/1-1367366400-1.gif",
        "period": "htt://chart-1-us.msw.ms/wave/750/1-1367366400-2.gif",
        "wind": "htt://chart-1-us.msw.ms/gfs/750/1-1367366400-4.gif",
        "pressure": "htt://chart-1-us.msw.ms/gfs/750/1-1367366400-3.gif",
        "sst": "htt://chart-1-us.msw.ms/sst/750/1-1367366400-10.gif"
    }
},
{
    "timestamp": 1367377200,
    "localTimestamp": 1367377200,
    "issueTimestamp": 1367366400,
    "fadedRating": 0,
    "solidRating": 0,
    "swell": {
        "minBreakingHeight": 0,
        "absMinBreakingHeight": 0.384,
        "maxBreakingHeight": 1,
        "absMaxBreakingHeight": 0.6,
        "unit": "ft",
        "components": {
            "combined": {
                "height": 1.8,
                "period": 4,
                "direction": 266.06,
                "compassDirection": "E"
            },
            "primary": {
                "height": 0.4,
                "period": 6,
                "direction": 92.53,
                "compassDirection": "W"
            },
            "secondary": {
                "height": 0.2,
                "period": 9,
                "direction": 52.72,
                "compassDirection": "SW"
            },
            "tertiary": {
                "height": 1.8,
                "period": 4,
                "direction": 258.73,
                "compassDirection": "ENE"
            }
        }
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 5,
        "direction": 255,
        "compassDirection": "ENE",
        "chill": 34,
        "gusts": 7,
        "unit": "mph"
    },
    "condition": {
        "pressure": 1025,
        "temperature": 41,
        "weather": "10",
        "unitPressure": "mb",
        "unit": "f"
    },
    "charts": {
        "swell": "htt://chart-1-us.msw.ms/wave/750/1-1367377200-1.gif",
        "period": "htt://chart-1-us.msw.ms/wave/750/1-1367377200-2.gif",
        "wind": "htt://chart-1-us.msw.ms/gfs/750/1-1367377200-4.gif",
        "pressure": "htt://chart-1-us.msw.ms/gfs/750/1-1367377200-3.gif",
        "sst": "htt://chart-1-us.msw.ms/sst/750/1-1367377200-10.gif"
    }
},  THIS CONTINUES ON UNTIL THE END OF THE ARRAY
```

How do I go about calling on the JSON Array and how can I assign a variable to each item (or access each item to use later in html etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: What programming language are you using and what have you done so far?

Comment: So far I've tried assigning the JSON array to a PHP variable by: <?php
$data = readfile("http://magicseaweed.com/api/MYAPIKEY/forecast/?spot_id=10");
//print_r ($data);

?>   I cant seem to call on any of the elements thought to assign them their own variables.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so if you're using PHP it's easy to access the JSON data, just use the [json_decode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) so you can access the data as a [PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and work with it easily.

Your code should follow this tasks:

1. Load the JSON data from the MagicSeaweed API URL;
2. Decode the JSON into a PHP array;
3. Process the PHP array and retrieve the fields you want.

In the following code you just need to replace `MYAPIKEY` with your real `APIKEY`, uncomment the line `$json = file_get_contents("magicseaweed.com/api/MYAPIKEY/forecast/?spot_id=10");` and comment the other line that's assigning the `$json` variable with the JSON subset example.

#### Code:

```
<?php
    // You should fetch the JSON data from the remote location the same
    // $json = file_get_contents("magicseaweed.com/api/MYAPIKEY/forecast/?spot_id=10");

    // This is just a subset JSON data for this example
    $json = '[{"timestamp":1367452800,"localTimestamp":1367452800,"issueTimestamp":1367452800,"fadedRating":0,"solidRating":0,"swell":{"minBreakingHeight":0,"absMinBreakingHeight":0,"maxBreakingHeight":0,"absMaxBreakingHeight":0,"unit":"ft","components":{"combined":{"height":2.5,"period":4,"direction":159.26,"compassDirection":"NNW"},"primary":{"height":1.9,"period":4,"direction":158.68,"compassDirection":"NNW"},"secondary":{"height":1.4,"period":5,"direction":255.73,"compassDirection":"ENE"}}},"wind":{"speed":8,"direction":182,"compassDirection":"N","chill":34,"gusts":13,"unit":"mph"},"condition":{"pressure":1024,"temperature":41,"weather":"10","unitPressure":"mb","unit":"f"},"charts":{"swell":"http:\/\/chart-1-us.msw.ms\/wave\/750\/1-1367452800-1.gif","period":"http:\/\/chart-1-us.msw.ms\/wave\/750\/1-1367452800-2.gif","wind":"http:\/\/chart-1-us.msw.ms\/gfs\/750\/1-1367452800-4.gif","pressure":"http:\/\/chart-1-us.msw.ms\/gfs\/750\/1-1367452800-3.gif","sst":"http:\/\/chart-1-us.msw.ms\/sst\/750\/1-1367452800-10.gif"}}]';

    // Decode the JSON data into a PHP array using 'true'
    // as 2nd argument of the json_decode function
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    // Iterate each of the records and access the data as needed
    foreach ($data as $record) {
        echo "Timestamp: {$record['timestamp']}\n";
        echo "Wind speed: {$record['wind']['speed']}\n";
        echo "Temperature: {$record['condition']['temperature']}\n";
    }
```

#### Output:

```
Timestamp: 1367452800
Wind speed: 8
Temperature: 41
```

Comment: My output still looks like an JSON Array http://surfwyre.com/report-page-test/  and when I try and echo something ex: echo $data[0][0]; it still show the entire array.

Comment: It works when I use the JSON example you provided but when I comment out the example and set it to use readfile() it still returns the entire JSON array and at the end throws Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I've gotten rid of the invalid foreach() error using the solution provide here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach but it is only returning the entire JSON array and not what I am trying to echo.

Comment: Just read the details I've added in the answer, you should be able to solve your problem on your own now... I don't know how I can help your further.

Comment: I've already uncommented $json = file_get_contents("magicseaweed.com/api/MYAPIKEY/forecast/?spot_id=10"); and replaced with my API key as well as commenting out the other json variable.  That is when the problem I described earlier occurs.  It returns an entire JSON array and doesn't echo out the fields I try to call on.  It also throws the error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Can you paste the result of `print_r($data);` after the line `$data = json_decode($json, true);` in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: There's a problem with it, that's not valid JSON, there's an extra value in the end: **42168**. And that's the result after the `json_decode()`? What about before?