# How to upload image on server in iPhone?

Tags: ios, image, upload

I am using this code to upload image on Server.. But in response I am getting this response from my web service. Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
-(IBAction)uploadToServer:(id)sender {
    NSString *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"jpeg"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: videoURL]];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youngdecade.com/test3/"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"uploadmultipleimage.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
    {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"file" fileName:@"1.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: request];
    [operation
        setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"response string=%@",operation.responseString);
        }
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error : %@",  operation.responseString);
        }
    ];
    [operation start];
}
```

uploadmultipleimage.php:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Multiple File Ppload with PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="uploadmultipleimage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post php code of the uploadmultipleimage.php ?

Comment: Are you using the last version of AFNetworking, the 2.0? It seems that the AFHTTPClient method has been deprecated.

Comment: I have this code with me rite now .<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multiple File Ppload with PHP</title>

</head>
<body>

  <form action="uploadmultipleimage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach

Comment: The same code i used for video uploading file with same AFNetworking Files.Just web service change And it worked perfectly.

Comment: IS my this IOS image uploading  code is correct???