# Failed insertion of tweets in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, twitter

```
 <?php
 require 'app_tokens.php';
 require 'tmhOAuth-master/tmhOAuth.php';
 $query = !empty($_GET['query']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['query']) : "shahrukh";

$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
'consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
'user_token' => $user_token,
'user_secret' => $user_secret
));

// Get the timeline with the Twitter API
$http_code = $connection->request('GET',$connection->url('1.1/search/tweets'),
array('q' => $query, 'count' => 20, 'lang' => 'en'));
// Request was successful
  if ($http_code == 200)
   {
      // Extract the tweets from the API response
      $response = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);
      $tweet_data = $response['statuses'];

     // Accumulate tweets from results
     $tweet_stream = '[';
        foreach ($tweet_data as $tweet)
           {
               // Add this tweet's text to the results

               $tweet_stream .= ' "<br>"{ "tweet":' . json_encode($tweet['text']) . ' },';
           }
     $tweet_stream = substr($tweet_stream, 0, -1);
     $tweet_stream .= ']';
   // Send the tweets back to the Ajax request
    print $tweet_stream;


// Connect to Mongo and set DB and Collection

$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->twitter;
$collection = $db->tweets;

// Convert JSON to a PHP array
$tweet_stream = json_decode($tweet_stream,true);

// Loop array and create seperate documents for each tweet
foreach ($tweet_stream as $item)
 {

 $collection->insert($item);
}


 // fetch all tweets from the collection
 $posts = $collection->find();

 foreach ($posts as $post) {
// display the posts
print $post;
  }
 }
// Handle errors from API request
else
  {
    if ($http_code == 429) 
      {
          print 'Error: Twitter API rate limit reached';
      }
   else 
     {
         print 'Error: Twitter was not able to process that request';
     }
}
```

The execution of above code  sucessfully retrieves the tweets related to shahrukh.The problem is it do not insert the tweets in mongodb and message given is " ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 51".Why is it so??Please go through it and hel me.

Comment: Your `$tweet_stream` value at line 51 is not an array or iterable object. You should `var_dump()` it to check the type and value. See also: [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach).

Answer (score 1):

you must change a line

```
$tweet_stream .= ' "<br>"{ "tweet":' . json_encode($tweet['text']) . ' },';
```

to

```
$tweet_stream .= '{ "tweet":' . json_encode($tweet['text']) . ' },';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback.I tried what you suggested but now it is giving this message. "( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 64"  How should be the conversion on line 64??

Comment: you should correct the line 64 `print_r($post);` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: Thanx a lott for your valuable help and guidance.It really helped me a lott.Hope you will quide me further as well if I face any problem.One last question on line number 4 of above code one message is displayed " ! ) Notice: Undefined index: query in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 4" .Why is it so?What correction is needed??

Comment: see line number 4 in your example

Comment: what message do you see?

Comment: "undefined index : query on line number 4"

Comment: there really is such this line: `$query = !empty($_GET['query']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['query']) : "shahrukh";`

Comment: Yes, Is there any problem in that line?