# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am getting this error in PHP / ZF2:

```
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

But **I can render the form elements.**
Why I am getting this error in Zend framework 2 and How to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you post the code here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Answer (score 1):

probably you are trying to loop throught a non-object or non-array variable

in case `$foo` should be an **object**:

```
if(is_object($foo)){
   foreach($foo as $element){
       // ...
   }
}
```

in case `$foo` should be an **array**:

```
if(is_array($foo)){
   foreach($foo as $element){
       // ...
   }
}
```

hope this helps