# Defining and calling custom function

Tags: php

I have a block of code that works perfect:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array($db->quoteName('date')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__webfoot_minutes_and_agendas'));
$query->order('date DESC'); 
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Until I try to assign it to a function:

```
function call_db() {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select(array($db->quoteName('date')));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__webfoot_minutes_and_agendas'));
    $query->order('date DESC'); 
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();   

    return $results;
}
```

It breaks when I try to call the function, I get an error for $results I get, "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...:

```
call_db();

foreach ($results as $result) {
   $dateArr = explode('-', $result->date);
       if (!in_array($dateArr[0], $already_echoed)) {
         echo '<li><a href="#tabs-' . $count . '">' . $dateArr[0] . '</a></li>';
       $count++;
       }
     $already_echoed[] = $dateArr[0];
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can straighten out this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign result of your function to variable.

```
$results = call_db();
```

Comment: Would this go in the function or before the loop?

Comment: Before loop. In place where you call this function now.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is awful design:

```
foreach (call_db() as $result) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned return value of call_db() to anything. You have to assign it first to `$results`

```
$results = call_db();
```

And, after that it is better if you check that the `$results` is an array. See [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Comment: Would this go in the function or before the loop?

Comment: Before the loop. This will replace the `call_db()` call that you have before the loop.