# Resolve Invalid argument for foreach() when adding sum of checkboxes

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, foreach, sum

Since I'm basically a designer and not a developer, I've bumped into a (probably pretty simple) problem that I can not seem to figure out.

**My problem:**

I want to add the value of the selected checkboxes together and display the sum of them as `$sum`. Pretty straightforward I thought, but I seem to **(1)** need some form of initial check if any checkboxes are posted to avoid `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`, as well as **(2)** some kind of prevention from posting without selecting any checkbox at all.

I've been trying to resolve my issue by looking at related threads such as [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach), and I've tried to use the solutions mentioned there, but unfortunately without success – you can see the lines I've commented out, `if (is_array($product)) {`.

**Goal**

My end goal with this code is to create a form with let's say 3 segments/categories of checkboxes where the user *must* check at least one `in each segment` (they could check all if they'd like, in my sample code only the first segment/category is supplied). Each checked box will provide a value that goes towards adding them all in a sum.

I'm happy to see any alternative solutions and optimizations, as long as you can explain or point me to an example of your improvements, since I'm very much a beginner with PHP.

**Index.php**

```
/* if (is_array($product)) { */
    foreach ($_POST['product'] as $name => $value) {
        $sum = array_sum(array_map('intval', $_POST['product']));

        echo('sum: '.$sum);

    }
/* } */

?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[1]" value="100" />100<br></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[2]" value="200" />200<br></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[3]" value="300" />300<br></label>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


<a href="index.php">reload</a>
```

Comment: `if (count($_POST['product'] )>0 ){....}`

Comment: Why are you calculating the sum in a loop? It's not going to change.

Comment: ^^ You really just need `array_sum($_POST['product'])`

Comment: To add to @Dagon 's suggestion, check also that it is an array before `count()`.  `if (is_array($_POST['product']) && count($_POST['product']) > 0)...`  You're on the right track with `is_array()` though.

Comment: ...Hmmm I just learned that `count(null)` returns 0, but you would still get an `undefined_index` notice if the array key isn't set so you should check first: `if (isset($_POST['product'] && count($_POST['product']) > 0) {...}` rather than `is_array()` which won't check the key's existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work :)

```
if (isset($_POST['product'])) {
    $product = $_POST['product'] ;
     if (is_array($product)) {
        foreach ($product as $name => $value) {
            $sum = array_sum(array_map('intval', $_POST['product']));

            echo('sum: ' . $sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Or slightly optimized :)

```
$product = $_POST['product'];
if(is_array($product)) {
    $sum = array_sum(array_map('intval', $product));
    echo('sum: ' . $sum);
}
```

The error comes up becaus `$_POST['product']` is not a valid array on the first run

## EDIT

You `is_array` would work, but I dont think you declared $product before using it, if you had, my guess is your code would work :)