# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.4

Hi can some one help me?  I got on all PHP Site's this failure :

The Code is insert via Plugin "NoNumber Sourcerer" in Joomla 3.4.1

```
bool(false) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/admin/libraries/class.System.php on line 117.
```

Here is Line 117 of the `class.system.php` :

```
foreach ($result as $entry) {
    $modulePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../modules/' . $entry['DirectoryName'] . '/';

    if (is_dir($modulePath) && $entry['DirectoryName'] != '.' && $entry['DirectoryName'] != '..') {
        if (is_file($modulePath . 'index.php')) {
                require_once $modulePath . 'index.php';

                $class = new ReflectionClass($entry['Class']);

                $module = $class->newInstance();

                $this->modules[] = $module;

                foreach ($module->getActions() as $action) {
                    $this->moduleMappings[$action] = $module;
                }

                if ($entry['IsDefault'] != 0) {
                    //print_R($module);
                    $this->defaultModule = $module;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the value supplied to foreach is not an array. Check that your `$result` variable contains an array. Try doing: `var_dump($result);` and see what you get.

Comment: i updated the code in the question

Comment: I think this error more related to Joomla setup instead of php coding error as error comes in a core file of Joomla. You need to change question details to show question as Joomla question or better move it to sister site  http://joomla.stackexchange.com/ where it got Joomla specific attention.

Comment: i insert the php code with the plugin "NoNumber Sourcerer" into joomla. The code was in use in a Typo3 Area without the error massage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if `$result` has values and update your code with -

```
if($result != NULL && is_array($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $entry) {
         // your conditions
    }
}
```

Comment: And if `$result` is a string or a integer ?

Comment: But I doubt that this will solve OP's real problem! I think the error is somewhere else in his code  that he doesn't get an array

Comment: might be, he can check and update here for further issues. We are here to help him :)

Comment: what is your output when you print $result ? Are you getting values in it, please update that as well in your question.

Comment: sorry, i'm not a profi with php. i'm updated the class.System.php . Now i see only " bool(false) " on every php site