# Phpvideotoolkit - "maxlen '=>' 3072 ' in buggedcom \ phpvideotoolkit \ src \ PHPVideoToolkit \ Mime.php line 202"

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to integrate PHPVideoToolKit in Symfony2, to generate prviews some videos.

Running directly from PHP I have no problem and works properly, but when in full in Symfony2, I stuck when he tells me that you can not convert a file larger than 3072.

```
"maxlen '=>' 3072 ')) in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ www \ VideoLab \ vendor \ buggedcom \ phpvideotoolkit \ src \ PHPVideoToolkit \ Mime.php line 202"
```

I added the Symfony library by:

```
"require": {
"ffmpeg-php / php-ffmpeg" "dev-master"
         "pulse00 / ffmpeg-bundle": "dev-master"
         "buggedcom / phpvideotoolkit" "dev-master"
```

and I installed all the libraries correctly in the Vendors.

The error is generated:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in \vendor\buggedcom\phpvideotoolkit\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Mime.php line 202

'maxlen' => '3072')) in \vendor\buggedcom\phpvideotoolkit\src\PHPVideoToolkit\Mime.php line 202
```

Not if you've encountered the problem and have a possible solution.

Than You very much
Xavier Collado

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled php_fileinfo.dll in config.ini XAMPP and everything worked perfectly.

Thank you very much for everything
Xavier Collado