# PHP- E_WARNING: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, foreach

How to solve `E_WARNING: Invalid argument supplied` for `foreach()` ?

for example:

This is the code

```
foreach ($response->myinterests as $key => $value) {
     foreach($value as $val)
    {
    $inter[$key][].= $val;
}
}
```

I want to add condition not equals empty

```
if(!empty($response->myinterests)){
        foreach ($response->myinterests as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $val)
    {
    $inter[$key][].= $val;
    }
}
        }
```

Is this right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Comment: Yes `!empty($response->myinterests)` is correct you can also use `count($response->myinterests) > 1`.

Comment: `$inter[$key][].=`........? Why concatenate (**`.`**)....?

Comment: That warning means that you are trying to traverse a *non-traversable* thing. You can basically traverse arrays and objects, so you must ensure you are giving `foreach` one of these types and not `null` or any scalar value.

Comment: Or you could type cast it:  `foreach ((array) $response->myinterests as $key => $value) {`  However if you get something like 0 which is non-traversable type casting it gives you array ( [0] => 0 ) instead of an empty array.  But I prefer the type-cast route.