# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "Invalid Argument"

Tags: php, mysql, arguments

**Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` on Line 865**

I'm Getting this error permanently:

```
  foreach ($prod as $key => $value) {
            $product[$key] = $prod[$key];
        }
        if ($prod["visibility"] == 'true') {
            if($this->storage->section["template"]=='')
                $this->storage->content = template('product', $product);
            else
                $this->storage->content = template('product', $product);
                // $this->storage->content = template('custom/'.$this->storage->section["template"], $product);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: `$prod` is not an array/iterable. That as much as I can help with the provided info...

Comment: It's impossible to figure out what the problem is without seeing the code that creates `$prod`.

Comment: just print_r($prod) before foreach and check what are you getting ?

Comment: can you show `var_dump($prod);` it seems that it is not an array

Comment: I just saw a `return` in there. Since you didn't post the rest of the code, It could be that you are not passing a valid `$prod` to the function - or not passing it at all...

Comment: its duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your array `$prod` is empty.

Add a condition [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) before `foreach` like this:

```
if (! empty($prod)) {
  foreach ($prod as $key => $value) {
    // Your Code
  }
}
else {
  // No records found
}
```

This will check if the array provided to `foreach` is not empty and loop over it only if it has records.

Thus, it will not show any errors/warnings.

Also, please go through your code and check why `$prod` is not getting data.

Is it a condition that is causing no data or there is some error.

That will solve this problem permanently along with above solution.

Comment: Just a note: this could be considered a hack IN CASE there should be `prods`. What I'm saying is that the op should also look for the REASON behind the empty `$prod` ^^. **Edit:** checking for `is_array` or something like that would be even better to prevent that type of error (because if `$prod` is `5`, for example, it will still be `!empty` - but invalid for a `foreach`)

Comment: @FirstOne, your suggestion is added in my answer. Thank your for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry but, I just noted this xD: _It seems that your array `$prod` is empty_. That is not true. `$foo = array();` is an empty array and it is a valid argument for a `foreach` - it just won't enter the `foreach`, but it still won't throw that error. This causes this answer to be a bit off. As I mentioned in the other comment: _if `$prod` is `5`, for example, it will still be `!empty` - but invalid for a `foreach`_

Comment: Thank You All for your quick reply
I edited and Changed as 

if (! empty($prod)) {
   foreach ($prod as $key => $value) {
                $product[$key] = $prod[$key];
            }
   }

I'll check it for the error