# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Tags: php, foreign-keys

the error log file that appears with this error:

Error on Oct 17, 2016 1:44AM - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/xxxxx/public_html/root/controllers/post/admin.php on line 391

```
private function curlMultiRequest($urls, $options = array()) {
        $ch = array();
        $results = array();
        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        foreach($urls as $key => $val) {        < -------------391 row
            $ch[$key] = curl_init();
            if ($options) {
                curl_setopt_array($ch[$key], $options);
            }
            curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_URL, $val);
            curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$key]);
        }
```

Comment: At least show us how you call this function as that is where the mistake is. You are obviously not passing an array as the `$urls` parameter on the function call

Answer (score 0):

`$urls` must be array so you could do this:

```
...
if(is_array($urls)){
    foreach($urls as $key => $val){
        ...
    }
}else{
    // handle unexpected state
}
...
```

or

```
private function curlMultiRequest(array $urls, $options = array()) { ... }
```

Comment: You can write it all to change completely what to do then just replace

Comment: Actually it would be valid if an empty array was passed. It would just not do anything inside the `foreach()` in that case

Answer (score 0):

Because $url being passed isn't an array or is empty?  Try doing this to see what is being passed to the function:

```
print_r($url);exit;
```

Comment: You can write it all to change completely what to do then just replace

Answer (score -1):

you have to check if the argument is an array or not
and you can take alook at this situation
[Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)