# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() line 48

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to fix this error messages:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning Message: Invalid
>   argument supplied for foreach()
>   Filename: views/editpages.php
>   Line Number: 48

---

Line 48:  `<?php foreach ($pages as $pages_item): ?>`

---

views/editpages.php

```
<div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">


                <?php foreach ($pages as $pages_item): ?>

                <div class="widget-box">
                    <div class="widget-title"><h5>Pages</h5></div>
                    <div class="widget-content">

                    <?php echo form_open('cpages/editpagesupdate'); ?>
                    <table border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 90px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Pages Name</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="pages_name" value="<?php echo $pages_item['pages_name']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Create Date</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="create_date" value="<?php echo $pages_item['create_date']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
                            <td>Order</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="pages_order" value="<?php echo $pages_item['pages_order']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>View Content</td>
                            <td><textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="pages_content"><?php echo $pages_item['pages_content']; ?></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="edit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>            
                    </div>
                </div>      

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
```

controllers/Cpages.php

```
public function editpages() {

    $data['pagessuccess'] = '';

    $pages_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['pages'] = $this->Mpages->call_point_pages($pages_id);

    $this->load->view('editpages', $data); 

}
```

models/Mpages.php

```
public function call_point_pages($pages_id)
{

    $this->db->where('pages_id', $pages_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('pages');
    //return $query->result_array();
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: according to your foreach you get n number of forms and tables. But all the form action goes to one  method. Check your code with is this archive your purpose. ex: if you had 15 array in foreach you get 15 table and 15 forms. But one form action URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Comment: @Davy .try to print before foreach . print_r($pages); exit; check what data you get

Comment: @Davy i think $pages has no array data

Comment: Well a few things to checkout... Do you have a segment(3) value and what happens when you don't? Are you checking that a valid result comes back from your query, ie is what is in $data['pages'] an array or something else? I'm hinting on being able to debug these things via inspecting the result of each step and being able to handle exceptions to what you expect.

Comment: Try adding `$data['pages'] = array();` above here `$data['pages'] = $this->Mpages->call_point_pages($pages_id);`

Answer (score 0):

Controller/cpages.php

```
public function editpages() {
    $data['pagessuccess'] = '';
    $pages_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['pages'] = $this->Mpages->call_point_pages($pages_id);
    $this->load->view('editpages', $data); 
}
```

models/Mpages.php

```
public function call_point_pages($pages_id) {
    $this->db->where('pages_id', $pages_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('pages');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Only one result will be get because there is a where condition and that seems like a primary key

so your View must like

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">    
<div class="widget-box">
<div class="widget-title"><h5>Pages</h5></div>
<div class="widget-content">
<?php echo form_open('cpages/editpagesupdate'); ?>
<table border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 90px;">
<?php foreach ($pages as $pages_item) { ?>
<tr>
<td>Pages Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="pages_name" value="<?php echo $pages_item->pages_name; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Create Date</td>
<td><input type="text" name="create_date" value="<?php echo $pages_item-   >create_date; ?>"></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<td>Order</td>
<td><input type="text" name="pages_order" value="<?php echo $pages_item->pages_order; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>View Content</td>
<td><textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="pages_content"><?php echo $pages_item->pages_content; ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" class="edit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>            
</div>
</div>      
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have already debugged and figured out the issue based on the comments and responses posted here..

this is just a tip:

Whenever, you have a method that is supposed to return array - you should have an empty array declaration inside that method. And then later on assign value/values to that array. This way you will always be able to use the returned value inside a foreach loop without worrying about whether the returned value is actually an array or not.

e.g.

```
public function call_point_pages($pages_id) {
    $pages = array();

    $this->db->where('pages_id', $pages_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('pages');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
            $page = object2array($row);
            $pages[] = $page;
        }
        $query->free_result();
    }
    return $pages;
}
```

This looks like a lot of code, but it has saved me from un expected errors at run time.