# PHP > Invalid Argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, json, mysqli

In short, I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my foreach statement. I have been trying to work on finding the error for over a day know and I'm running out of time. This program is supposed to parse a json array and post it up to a mysqli database.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$a = print_r(var_dump($GLOBALS),1);
echo htmlspecialchars($a);

$servername = "#";
$username = "#";
$password = "#";
$dbname = "#";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
echo "Connection Successful : ";

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Read JSON file
$jsondata = file_get_contents('scripts/AUDIT_DIR/report.json');
echo "JSON File Read : ";

// Convert and Loop
$item = json_decode($jsondata, true);
echo "JSON File Decoded : ";

foreach($item as $arr)
{
    $id = $arr["id"];
    $hostname = $arr["hostname"];
    $ip = $arr["ip"];
    $package = $arr["package"];
    $publisher = $arr["publisher"];
    $origin = $arr["origin"];
    $version = $arr["version"];
    $size = $arr["size"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO testtable(id, hostname, ip, package, publisher, origin, version, size)
    VALUES ('10', '$hostname', '$ip', '$package', '$publisher', '$origin', '$version', '$size')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        echo "New record created successfully : ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: `$item` is supposed to be an array. Have you checked it?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: Can you do a var_dump on the $item and post the output here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Answer (score 0):

You likely have an invalid return from your `json_decode()` you can check this with a `var_dump($item);` after your `json_decode()`

In php `json_decode()` will return NULL if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

You need to properly guard for such a case that `$item === null` and not assume you will always get a valid return for your `foreach()` params.

Example showing your error happens when `$item = null`
https://3v4l.org/oNr8P

Comment: Connection Successful : JSON File Read : NULL JSON File Decoded :
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/jsonparse.php on line 30

Comment: Exactly your json decode is null. You need to handle that case in your code. additionally you need to figure out why the json decode is null, maybe your json file isn't being read or is not proper json format.