# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I have an error in the product detail, I do not know what else to change where again. when I change `$detail` into `$categories` succeed but is the same as function submenu. It was not according to my wishes

My View

```
<!-- navbar -->
<div class="row">
<?php foreach ($categories as $row) : ?>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
         <h5><?php echo $row->categoriesName; ?></h5>
         <ul><li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>member/detail">
         <?php echo $row->productName; ?></a> </li></ul>
     </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
     <!-- product detail -->
     <?php foreach ($detail as $details_new) : ?>
     <div class="box">
         <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $details_new->productName;?></h1>
         <p class="price"><?php echo $details_new->price;?></p>
     </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

My Controller

```
public function home() {
    $data=array('title'=>'Pasar Online | Ayo Belanja Sekarang',
          'username'=> $this->session->userdata('username'),
          'product' => $this->product_model->all(),
          'categories' => $this->categories_model->get_main(),
          'isi'  =>'member/index');    
    $this->load->view('template_home/wrapper',$data);
}
public function detail() {
    $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['categories'] = $this->categories_model->get_main();
    $data['detail'] = $this->categories_model->get_details();
    $this->load->view('member/coba',$data);
}
```

My Model

```
public function get_main(){
    $this->db->select('product.*,categories.*');
    $this->db->from('product');
    $this->db->join('categories','product.categoriesID=categories.categoriesID');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $results = $query->result();
    } return $results;
}       
public function get_details() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID");
    $row = $query->row();
}
```

[image]

still can not display a single product

[image]

I do not know where my mistake... please help me, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Comment: what should be I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codeigniter `row()` selects only first row of your result in object format.So no need to use foreach loop.Just try like this...

```
     <div class="box">
         <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $detail->productName;?></h1>
         <p class="price"><?php echo $detail->price;?></p>
     </div>
```

And 
In model

```
public function get_details() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID");
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: I want to make details on the products when the consumers choose a subcategory

Comment: use ajax to fetch detail on the basis of subcategory id?

Comment: still can not display a product and I do not add it to the ajax

Comment: you are sending to different views so no need to use ajax.But i don't understand your problem clearly.

Comment: if every thing is fine above code will display your details correctly.

Comment: @Rahmat Always use the concept of first right in first accept.If you are new in stack.

Comment: but why only one can be displayed at Subcategory?? subcategory that others could not and that always appear first subcategory

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating details array in wrong format.

```
public function get_details() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID");
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row;
}
```

This will return only single row without any indexing like - 0,1,2...

and on view page you are using foreach loop and foreach loop use indexing to iterate value you can iterate like that --

```
<div class="box">
         <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $detail->productName; ?></h1>
         <p class="price"><?php echo $detail->price; ?></p>
     </div>
```

please use this way hope it will work..

Comment: but why only one can be displayed at Subcategory??

Comment: your welcome...sorry i didn`t get your question....also can you please provide upvote if my answer was helpful to you?

Comment: but why only one can be displayed at Subcategory?? subcategory that others could not and that always appear first subcategory

Comment: you mean why its display result without indexing ??

Comment: so when I click subcategory it will display the detailed subcategories

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779813/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-product-detail-in-subcategories

Answer (score 0):

it is because of $detail variable is empty, no data available in this variable, always check for data in variable before looping

```
<?php if(!empty($detail)){    
     foreach ($detail as $details_new) : ?>
 <div class="box">
     <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $details_new->productName;?></h1>
     <p class="price"><?php echo $details_new->price;?></p>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach; } ?>
```

Comment: <?php 
if(!empty($detail)){    
foreach ($detail as $details_new) { ?>
<div class="box">
<h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $details_new->productName;?></h1>
<p class="price"><?php echo $details_new->price;?></p>
</div>
<?php  } } ?>

Comment: there is no appearance, I want to display a single product