# Trying to get property of non-object product detail in subcategories

Tags: php, codeigniter, categories, display

I want to show one product of sub-categories selected, but there was an error `message: Trying to get property of non-object` in view product detail, please to be corrected if there are mistakes in the controller, model, and view.

where is my mistake?

View

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $key=>$value) { ?>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
     <h5><?php echo $categories[$key]->categoriesName; ?></h5>
         <?php if(count($categories[$key]->subs)>0) { ?>
             <?php foreach ($categories[$key]->subs as $k=>$v)  { ?>
                   <ul>
                      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>member/detail/"><?php echo $v->productName; ?></a> </li>
                   </ul>
             <?php } ?>
             <?php } ?>
        </div>
  <?php } ?>
<div class="row" id="productMain">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="mainImage"><img src="<?php echo base_url('upload/'.$details->photo);?>"
         alt="" class="img-responsive">div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="box">
            <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $details->productName;?></h1>
            <p class="price">
                <?php echo $details->price;?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model

```
public function get_categories() {
    $query = $this->db->get('categories');
    $return = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $category) {
        $return[$category->categoriesID] = $category;
        $return[$category->categoriesID]->subs = 
        $this->get_sub_categories($category->categoriesID);
    }
    return $return;
}

public function get_sub_categories($category_id) {
    $this->db->where('categoriesID', $category_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('product');
    return $query->result();
}

public function get_details($product_id) 
{
    $this->db->where("productID",$product_id);
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product");
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row;
}
```

Controller

```
public function detail($product_id){
     $data=array('title'   =>'Pasar Online | Detail Produk',
           'username'      => $this->session->userdata('username'),
           'categories'    => $this->categories_model->get_categories(),
           'details'       => $this->categories_model->get_details($product_id),
           'isi'           =>'member/detail');
     $this->load->view('template_home/wrapper',$data);
 }
```

print_r($categories)

```
Array ( [1] => stdClass Object 
( [categoriesID] => 1 [categoriesName] => Laptop [subs] => Array 
    ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [productID] => P0001 [categoriesID] => 1 [productName] => AAA ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [productID] => P0002 [categoriesID] => 1 [productName] => BBB ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [productID] => P0004 [categoriesID] => 1 [productName] => CCC ) ) ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [categoriesID] => 2 [categoriesName] => TV [subs] => Array
    ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [productID] => P0005 [categoriesID] => 2 [productName] => loren epsum ) ) ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [categoriesID] => 3 [categoriesName] => Handphnone [subs] => Array 
    ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [productID] => P0003 [categoriesID] => 3 [productName] => Manggoes ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [productID] => P0006 [categoriesID] => 3 [productName] => Pinneapple ) ) ) )
```

print_r($details)

```
stdClass Object ( [productID] => P0001 [categoriesID] => 1 [productName] => AAA ) 1
```

the fault is in the loop `$details`

Comment: what is output on `print_r($categories)`?

Comment: I've edited, so no one in the loop but when I choose the 'product details' shown is error

Comment: you have to pass id .try you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...in view:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $key=>$value) { ?>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
           <h5><?php echo $categories[$key]->categoriesName; ?></h5>
           <?php if(count($categories[$key]->subs)>0) { ?>
           <?php foreach ($categories[$key]->subs as $k=>$v)  { ?>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>member/detail">
                         <?php echo $v->productName; ?></a></li>
                 </ul>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
      </div>
 <?php } ?>

<div class="row" id="productMain">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="mainImage"><img src="<?php echo base_url('upload/'.$details->photo);?>"
         alt="" class="img-responsive">div>
    </div>
<?php if(count($details)>0){
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="box">
            <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $details->productName;?></h1>
            <p class="price">
                <?php echo $details->price;?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

MODEL:

Send product_id in where condition for product details

```
  public function get_details($product_id) {
    $this->db->where("productID",$product_id);
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product");
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: This still erorr, an error message trying to get property of non-object in '$detail' in view

Comment: try edited answer.your array is empty.Just count array.

Comment: I already also edited but still no results display of the product detail, I insert print_r but its results like this 'Array () 1'

Comment: send id to details function of your model,

Comment: it is just one product that can be displayed while I want to be able to show other products when selected

Comment: you have to pass id .try you can do.

Comment: if you not get result..hope i will help.

Comment: is there any other way with my model?

Comment: functions such as empty and count, do you have any references? I want to learn it..

Comment: first of all get all the products inside category from category_id then call the details function for each product.

Comment: I've edited my controller, view and print_r, but there is only one that can be displayed in accordance with print_r

Comment: first need to get all the product ids for each category then foreach product ids call to details function.