# Trying to get property of non-object CodeIgniter and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter

php version 5.3.1 with codeigniter 2.0.2

help me, i have errors like this :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: controllers/login.php

Line Number: 20
```

Controller

```
parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('option_m');
    $option = $this->option_m->get_by(array('nama_opsi' => 'store_option'));
    foreach (unserialize($option->value_opsi) as $key => $val) {
        $this->data->$key = $val;
    }
    $this->template->use_asset()->set_judul('Form Login')->set_css('login');

    $this->data->metadata = $this->template->get_metadata();
    $this->data->judul = $this->template->get_judul();
}
```

in the sublime text, line number 20 is, but im not sure:

```
foreach (unserialize($option->value_opsi) as $key => $val) {
$this->data->$key = $val;
```

Comment: in Sublime text The Line Number 20 is : foreach (unserialize($option->value_opsi) as $key => $val) {

but im not sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Comment: what is the raw value of `$option->value_opsi`?

Comment: $option->value_opsi is query from table option

Answer (score 0):

Try storing `unserialize($option->value_opsi)` in an intermediate variable and print it out. I'm betting that's not an array format that foreach can accept.

Answer (score 0):

First verify if $option is valid before using it, otherwise you will end up trying to access values from an invalid return. Suppose your query returned $option = false, then you tried to access a field from it like $option->value, then you will get the same error.

I suggest you to put a if statement before using it:

```
if($option) { foo; bar; ...}
```

And use unserialize only if $option->value_opsi is a serialized value.

Hope it helped.