# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ( Contact form )

Tags: php, foreach, contact-form

this contact form it's not working, 
Please Anyone could help me? 
PS : I understand nothing in php

Below contact form script.

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in htdocs/bat/MailHandler.php on line 54

```
<?php
    $owner_email='habib@site.com'; 
    //SMTP server settings  
    $host = 'smtp.site.com';
    $port = '25';//"587";
    $username = ''; 
    $password = '';

    $subject='A message from your site visitor ';
    $user_email='';    
    $message_body='';
    $message_type='html';

    $max_file_size=50;//MB 
    $file_types='/(doc|docx|txt|pdf|zip|rar)$/';
    $error_text='something goes wrong';
    $error_text_filesize='File size must be less than';
    $error_text_filetype='Failed to upload file. This file type is not allowed. Accepted files types: doc, docx, txt, pdf, zip, rar.';

    // $private_recaptcha_key='6LeZwukSAAAAACmqrbLmdpvdhC68NLB1c9EA5vzU'; //localhost


    $use_recaptcha=isset( $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]) and isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    $use_smtp=($host=='' or $username=='' or $password=='');
    $max_file_size*=1048576;

    if($owner_email=='' || $owner_email=='#'){
        die('Attention, recipient e-mail is not set! Please define "owner_email" variable in the MailHanlder.php file.');
    }

    if(preg_match('/^(127\.|192\.168\.)/',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
        die('Attention, contact form will not work locally! Please upload your template to a live hosting server.');
    }

    if($use_recaptcha){
        require_once('recaptchalib.php');
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($private_recaptcha_key,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
        if (!$resp->is_valid){
            die ('wrong captcha');
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['name']) and $_POST['name'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n"; $subject.=$_POST['name'];}
    if(isset($_POST['email']) and $_POST['email'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n"; $user_email=$_POST['email'];}
    if(isset($_POST['state']) and $_POST['state'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['phone']) and $_POST['phone'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}   
    if(isset($_POST['fax']) and $_POST['fax'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
    if(isset($_POST['message']) and $_POST['message'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";}  
    if(isset($_POST['stripHTML']) and $_POST['stripHTML']=='true'){$message_body = strip_tags($message_body);$message_type='text';}


try {
    include "libmail.php";

    foreach ($owner_email as $owner_email_item) {
        $m= new Mail("utf-8");
        $m->From($user_email);
        $m->To($owner_email_item);
        $m->Subject($subject);
        $m->Body($message_body,$message_type);
        //$m->log_on(true);

        if(isset($_FILES['attachment'])){
            if($_FILES['attachment']['size']>$max_file_size){
                $error_text=$error_text_filesize . ' ' . $max_file_size . 'bytes';
                die($error_text);           
            }else{          
                if(preg_match($file_types,$_FILES['attachment']['name'])){
                    $m->Attach($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name'],'','attachment');
                }else{
                    $error_text=$error_text_filetype;
                    die($error_text);               
                }
            }       
        }
        if(!$use_smtp){
            $m->smtp_on( $host, $username, $password, $port);
        }

        $m->Send();
    }   

    die('success'); 

}catch(Exception $mail){
    die($mail);
}   
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` on line 54 expects that you pass it an array (or array like object) but you're passing it a string. See the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for more information.

On your second line, change `$owner_email='habib@site.com';` to `$owner_email=array('habib@site.com');`

Comment: Feel free to accept this then as the correct answer (click the checkmark underneath the voting)!