# PHP - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, html, arrays

I did look up this error and people say that it is caused by an empty array, but as you can see, I have entries for my array. Or that the variable isn't an array, which it is. I am unsure as to why this doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<? php 
    $posts = array();
    $posts[0] = array(
        'user' => 'Bob',
        'message' => 'This is a post',
        'image' => 'image/picture.jpg',
        'date' => '20/4/17');
    $posts[1] = array(
        'user' => 'James',
        'message' => 'This is also a post',
        'image' => 'image/picture.jpg',
        'date' => '20/4/15');
    $posts[2] = array(
        'user' => 'Steve',
        'message' => 'This is also also a post',
        'image' => 'image/picture.jpg',
        'date' => '20/4/13');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Social Media</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Social Media </h1>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post){?>
    <p>
        <?= $post['user'] ?>
        <?= $post['message'] ?>
        <?= $post['date'] ?>
        <?= $post['image'] ?>
    </p>
    <?php } ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls tell me the output of var_dump($posts);

Comment: Change your first line with `<?php` i mean remove the space .

Comment: @mim. ah one space messed everything up... love coding. That fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Check this question's solutions and check if they work for you.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2630013/5350773

Answer (score 0):

You have array of array for that you have to specify which array value you want to echo like,

```
echo $post[0]['user'];
```

It will print user from `$posts[0]`.

```
<?php
 $c = 0;
 foreach ($posts as $post){?>
<p>
    <?= $post[$c]['user'] ?>
    <?= $post[$c]['message'] ?>
    <?= $post[$c]['date'] ?>
    <?= $post[$c]['image'] ?>
</p>
<?php
$c++;
 } ?>
```

Comment: foreach loop is just a loop how come it integrate as you want, for that use a counter value which increment as you loop.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually tested above code and I dont see any issue with your code but its possible that you've turned all your error_reporting to E_ALL or something but anyways you can try below make sure to check if the object is an array or not

```
if (is_array($posts)) 
{
  foreach ($posts as $post)
  {
       //do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@mim. noticed a stray space in the opening php tag, removing it fixed this problem.