# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() search results

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to implement a filtering system in my web application, whereby users can filter their list of items by category. However, the following error message is being displayed

```
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in foreach ($item as $key => $val)"
```

and I'm not entirely certain why. I've tried various approaches to overcome this issue such as trying to set `$items` as an array, but it's still not successful. Without implementing the search system, the items for the specific user are correctly displayed, however as soon as I implement the filter, the error message above is displayed.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**items.php**

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Items</div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Search for Items</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <div class="card-body items">
           <table class = "items">

           <?php
           $itemsObject = new items($database); 
           $item = $itemsObject->getItemsForUser($_SESSION['userData']['userid'], $_POST['search']); 
           foreach ($item as $key => $val) { 
              echo '<tr><td>'.$val['cat_name'].'</td><td>'.$val['amount'].'</td></tr>';   
      }
?>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**items.classes.php**

```
   public function getItemsForUser($userid, $search = null){
      if(!isset($search)){
        $query = "SELECT i.*, c.cat_name, c.cat_id FROM items AS i INNER JOIN categories AS c ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id WHERE userid = :userid";
        $pdo = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $pdo->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
        } else {
                $query = "SELECT i.*, c.cat_name, c.cat_id FROM items AS i INNER JOIN categories AS c ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id WHERE userid = :userid AND c.cat_name LIKE :search";
            $pdo = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $pdo->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
            $pdo->bindParam(':search', $search);
        }
       $pdo->execute();
       return $pdo->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: check your $item array is blank or not using print_r($item);die();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Comment: There is a TYPO mistake in your `items.classes.php`. Do it like,  `$query = "SELECT i.*, c.cat_name, c.cat_id FROM items AS i INNER JOIN categories AS c ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id WHERE userid = :userid";`

Comment: You missed a (") on the end of the line $query = "SELECT i.*, c.cat_name, c.cat_id FROM items AS i INNER JOIN categories AS c ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id WHERE userid = :userid;

Answer (score 1):

Put the execute query outside the if/else

```
if(isset($search)){
    $search = '%'.$search.'%';
    $query = "SELECT i.*, c.cat_name, c.cat_id FROM items AS i INNER JOIN categories AS c ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id WHERE userid = :userid AND c.cat_name LIKE :search";
    $pdo = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $pdo->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
    $pdo->bindParam(':search', $search);
} else {
        $query = "SELECT i.*, c.cat_name, c.cat_id FROM items AS i INNER JOIN categories AS c ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id WHERE userid = :userid";
        $pdo = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $pdo->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
}

$pdo->execute(); // <---- HERE
return $pdo->fetchAll();
```

Comment: This eliminates the error, however the table is no longer being displayed?

Comment: probably because you don't have any results

Comment: I've rearranged the structure of the query, however the results are not being filtered and I'm not entirely sure why. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you remove the filters from the query (just SELECT * FROM table), it return any result?

Comment: I've sorted it now, but thanks for your help! Also, if I wanted to clear the search without refreshing the page, how would I go about doing that?