# INNER JOIN and foreach loop on php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have problem with foreach loop and inner join on php.
I have two tables: toners and printers. And code:

```
$toner = $this->_db->execute('SELECT TONERS.NAME, PRINTERS.NAME, TONERS.CONTRACTORS FROM TONERS INNER JOIN PRINTERS ON TONERS.ID_PRINTERS=PRINTERS.ID;')
foreach ($toner as $toners) {
            //here is the html table with results
}
```

receives an error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().
I'll add that on the query without 'Inner join' everything works fine ...

Anyone have an idea?
Please...

Comment: Apparently, query return less than or equal to one row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` fails like this if `$toner` is null. The inner join is returning no rows. You need logic to handle this case. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach) for more info about this error.

Answer (score 0):

At first, try to run this query on a server (like in PHPMyAdmin) and check that there are some records to fill your variable, which is used in foreach loop. This error shows you that your `$toner` var is empty.

Then try to fetch data from your query

```
$sql = "SELECT TONERS.NAME, PRINTERS.NAME, TONERS.CONTRACTORS FROM TONERS INNER JOIN PRINTERS ON TONERS.ID_PRINTERS=PRINTERS.ID;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     //do your magic
}
```