# Getting "undefined offset" and "invalid argument" errors

Tags: php, php-7

I get these errors when I go the `Reports.php` page:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined offset: 0
>   Filename: controllers/Reports.php
>   Line Number: 73
>   Backtrace:
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurant\application\controllers\Reports.php
>   Line: 73
>   Function: _error_handler
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurant\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   Filename: controllers/Reports.php
>   Line Number: 88
>   Backtrace:
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurant\application\controllers\Reports.php
>   Line: 88
>   Function: _error_handler
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurant\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

This is line 73 in `Reports.php`:

```
$store_id = $store_data[0]['id'];
```

This is line 88 in `Reports.php`:

```
foreach ($order_data as $k => $v) {
```

This is line 315 in `index.php`:

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Comment: `$store_data[0]['id'];` the 0 of that array does not exist. you want to check whats in  `$store_data` `var_dump( $store_data);`

Comment: See [Notice: Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836) and [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach).

Comment: your `store_data`  array does not have any element on zero place to check your array you can use `print_r(store_data)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)