# codeigniter form_hidden do not POST data

Tags: php, codeigniter

failed to POST `$items['id']` data array into database if i use  `form_hidden('product_id[]', $items['id'])` ,however if i use `form_input('product_id[]', $items['id'])` all  `$items['id']` array can be insert into database without error,i need help because i want to use `form_hidden()`.

[image]

view(html) :

```
foreach ($item as $items) { ?>

          <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
              <div class="avatar avatar-md">
                <img src="./assets/avatars/face-3.jpg" alt="..." class="avatar-img rounded-circle">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <p class="mb-0"><?= $items['product_name'] ?></p>
              <small class="mb-0">[ <?= $items['serial_number'] ?> ]</small>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div>
                  <small>
                  B :    
                  <?php
                    if($items['berat']!=0)
                    {
                      echo $items['berat'].' g';
                    }else{
                      echo '-';
                    }
                  ?>  
                  </small>
                  <br>
                  <small>
                  P :    
                  <?php
                    if($items['panjang']!=0)
                    {
                      echo $items['panjang'].' cm';
                    }else{
                      echo '-';
                    }
                  ?>  
                  </small>
                  <br>
                  <small>
                  L :    
                  <?php
                    if($items['lebar']!=0)
                    {
                      echo $items['lebar'].' cm';
                    }else{
                      echo '-';
                    }
                  ?>  
                  </small>
                </div>

                <div class="ml-3">
                  <small>
                  Sz :    
                  <?php
                    if($items['saiz']!=0)
                    {
                      echo $items['saiz'];
                    }else{
                      echo '-';
                    }
                  ?>  
                  </small>
                  <br>
                  <small>
                  Sb :    
                  <?php
                    if($items['serial_berat']!='')
                    {
                      echo $items['serial_berat'];
                    }else{
                      echo '-';
                    }
                  ?>  
                  </small>
                  <br>
                  <small>
                  M :    
                  <?php
                    if($items['mutu']!='')
                    {
                      echo $items['mutu'];
                    }else{
                      echo '-';
                    }
                  ?>  
                  </small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="w-25 text-center">
              <p class="mb-0"><?= $items['keterangan'] ?></p>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center"><?= $items['harga'] ?></td>
          </tr>

          
       <?php echo form_hidden('product_id[]', $items['id']); ?>


        <?php } } ?>
```

controller :

```
//CONTROLLER
$arr_buyID = $this->input->post('product_id[]');

$buy = array(
  'cust_id' => $this->input->post('things'),
  'seller' => $this->data['user_profile']['full_name'],
  'total_harga' => $this->input->post('jumlah'),
  'created_date'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
);
$this->db->insert('ci_buy', $buy);
$buy_id = $this->db->insert_id();

for($i=0;$i<count($arr_buyID);$i++){
  
  $res = explode('_',$arr_buyID[$i]);
  $item = array(
    'buy_id'=>$buy_id,
    'status'=>1
  );
  $this->db->where('id', $arr_buyID[$i]);
  $this->db->update('ci_buy_product', $item);
}
```

sample array `print_r($item)` :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 13 [buy_id] => [product_name] => QWEW [serial_number] => BL00000013 [dulang] => [category] => [mutu_id] => 1 [serial_berat] => 0.370 [berat] => 1.00 [saiz] => 2 [panjang] => 3.00 [lebar] => 0.00 [harga] => 1.00 [keterangan] => asd [status] => 2 [picture] => [mutu] => 999 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 [buy_id] => [product_name] => ASD [serial_number] => BL00000014 [dulang] => [category] => [mutu_id] => 1 [serial_berat] => 0.370 [berat] => 1.00 [saiz] => 2 [panjang] => 3.00 [lebar] => 0.00 [harga] => 12.00 [keterangan] => asdasd [status] => 2 [picture] => [mutu] => 999 ) ) 1
```

my view if i use `form_input` which show the `$item['id']` (13 and 14) inside `form_input`,this method no error,if i hide the form input using `form_hidden`,it will show error

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Show the **HTML** code.

Comment: @azri, Can you show us how a sample `$items` array looks like?

Comment: i added sample array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

You have foreach problem inside view, not in controller.
maybe you have misspell error?

```
foreach ($item as $items)
```

or maybe you have $items and you need such fix? (correct grammar)

```
foreach ($items as $item)
```

Comment: i checked,no misspell error,this is my model for $item `$this->data['item'] = $this->product_model->get_item();`

Answer (score 0):

Contoh hidden form :

```
<input type="hidden" id="kegiatan_dilakukan" name="kegiatan_dilakukan" autocomplete='off' class="form-control" value="0">
```