# Woocommerce PHP Warning for class-wc-admin-dashboard.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, warnings

Suddenly, my php log is getting flooded with this php warning:

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-dashboard.php on line 543', referer:

The warning always keep the same but the **referer** could be literally any page of the site, including back and front end. I really don't have a clue whats going on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Version of PHP, Wordpress and Woocommerce?

Comment: Everything is up to the latest version.
Wordpress 5.8.2
WooCommerce 5.9.0
PHP 7.4

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `foreach ( $data as $d ) {
    $total += $d['subtotals']->$meta_key;
    array_push( $sparkline_data, array( strval( strtotime( $d['interval'] ) * 1000 ), $d['subtotals']->$meta_key ) );
   }`

This is the line of code the warning is refering to

Answer (score 1):

Using a solution found in [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

You can edit 'class-wc-admin-dashboard.php' and add this code in line 543 (just before the foreach):

```
if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
```