# foreach() argument must be of type array | object, null given (Laravel Livewire)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

**This code is working fine**

```
public function render(){
    $this->products = ProductModel::get();
    return view('livewire.product');
}
```

**But when I am trying to paginate using laravel livewire, it gives me an error**

```
public function render(){
     return view('livewire.product', [
         'products' => ProductModel::paginate(10)
    ]);
}
```

**Blade File**

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
  {{ $product->name }}
  {{ $product->price }}
@endforeach

@if(!empty($products))
{{ $products->links() }}
@endif
```

Comment: You should provide the error.

Comment: Sorry, but it seem like issue is in your blade file. When you are passing data to product.blade.php file in second case, then it somewhere in foreach loop it expect giving array as parameter but you end up passing object return by ProductModel::paginate();

Comment: In `livewire.product` blade file, are you accessing to `$products` variable or to something else? In first case do don't even pass variable with `view` helper.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

import this in Component

```
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Product extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

....

}
```

and add in view

```
@if(!empty($products))
    {{ $products->links() }}
@endif
```

Comment: I have already done these steps

Answer (score 0):

Ohh I got it.Actually I have already use $products variable as a global variable
and when I change $products to other name it works.
Thanks alot...

Comment: please make sure you set this answer as accepted if this solved your problem.