# Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object

Tags: php, html

I am working on a WordPress website, and I am having trouble with the for each loop. Everything looks right, only it's giving me this error on my web page: Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object

```
<?php
get_header();
while (have_posts()){
    the_post(); ?>
    <div class="page-banner">
      <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images/connection.jpg') ?>');"></div>
      <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
        <h1 class="page-banner__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container container--narrow page-section">
    <div class="metabox metabox--position-up metabox--with-home-link">
        <p><a class="metabox__blog-home-link" href="<?php echo
        get_post_type_archive_link('event'); ?>"
          ><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Events Home</a> 
          <span class="metabox__main"><?php the_title(); ?></span></p>
          </div>

    
        <div class="generic_content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

        <?php 
        $dcHosts = get_field('event_host');
        
        foreach($dcHosts as $companies) {
          echo get_the_title($companies);
        }
        
        ?>
</div>
<?php }
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Apparently `$dcHosts` is not an array or an object. You'll need to figure out why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)