# foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given Laravel

Tags: laravel, database

I'm trying to retrieve data from database and display all the data using foreachloop. Im getting first row data easily without foreach loop but whenever I try using loop the error displays "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given"

This is my Controller Code

```
class dbcontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        
        $posts = DB::table('table1')->get();
       
           $d = $posts[0]->Name;
           $a =$posts[0]->Age;
        return view('db',compact('d','a'));
    
    }
}
```

And my Blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
        @foreach ($d as $user => $data)
            <p>This name {{ $data->name }}</p>
        @endforeach
    {{-- <p>Name is {{$d}} & Age is {{$a}}</p> --}}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$d` contains the *first* post's name. You can't foreach over it; you'd want to foreach over `$posts` instead, most likely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630013/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bring $posts for your foreach.

controller:

```
return view('db', compact('posts'));
```

in blade:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <p>{{ $post->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The get() method always returns a collection which can be used in foreach loop. Whereas The first element of get() will return a single model instance. Again, you are just sending a single attribute of that model to view not the collection itself. You can not just run any loop on single attribute. This is basic PHP.

**this will not work**

```
$d = $posts[0]->Name;
$a =$posts[0]->Age;

return view('db',compact('d','a'));
```

Following can be true for your scenario:

**Controller**:

```
class Dbcontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        
        $posts = DB::table('table1')->get();

        return view('db',compact('posts'));
    
    }
}
```

**blade**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <p>{{ $post->someAttribute }}</p>
        @endforeach

</body>
</html>
```

For references

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#retrieving-all-rows-from-a-table